# How to update Bootstrap Modal content?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I use ReactJs and Bootstrap 4. I have a static modal. I want to trigger modal with new data when every time I call the function.

The div element that class the function:

```
 <div className="session rounded hover-light " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sessionModal"  onClick={() => showEvent(session)}>
```

The showEvent function:

```
 const showEvent = (event = {}) => {
   return (
     <div className="modal fade" id="sessionModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="searchModal" aria-hidden="true">
       <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
         <div className="modal-content">
           <div className="modal-header">...</div>
           <div className="modal-body">
             <h5 className="mb-4">
               <u>Title : <strong>{session.name}</strong></u>
             </h5>
           </div>
         </div> 
       </div>)
```

Then return the function the dom like this:

```
{showEvent()}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, update your question with your code.

Comment: @tcj i have console.log in the funtion and return the data , but the modal always render static value

Comment: @benjaminRampon done

Answer (score 0):

Miled your function is wrong! The function argument is `event` but you wrote `{session.name}` instead of `{event.name}` when you wanted to use it. Just change it you'll be ok.